# DatabaseMetaData#getTables cannot find existing table in Derby

Tags: java, database, jdbc, derby

I'm connecting to Derby database in Java:

```
public EmbeddedDerbyDataConnection(String name) throws SQLException {

    EmbeddedDataSource dataSource = new EmbeddedDataSource();
    dataSource.setDatabaseName(name);
    dataSource.setCreateDatabase("create");

    this.connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    init();
}
```

Connection seems to be OK. Then I call `init()` method which creates table if it doesn't exists yet and fills this table with some default data:

```
private void init() throws SQLException {
    DatabaseMetaData metaData = this.connection.getMetaData();
    ResultSet rs = metaData.getTables(null, null, "mytable", null);
    if (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println("Table already exists.");
    } else {
        Statement stmt = this.connection.createStatement();
        String query = "CREATE TABLE mytable (...)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        stmt.close();

        stmt = this.connection.createStatement();
        query = "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (...)";
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        stmt.close();
    }
}
```

After creating object of EmbeddedDerbyDataConnection for the first time, it seemed OK. I tested it by `SELECT * FROM mytable` and it returned that default data I put in this table.

After the second call, I get: `Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Table/View 'mytable' already exists in Schema 'APP'.` It looks like the ResultSet rs in `init()` method is empty. However, after calling `SELECT * FROM mytable`, data are there and they are correct.

How can I fix this? Where can be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Derby's implementation of `.getTables` appears to be case-sensitive, and Derby also appears to force your table name to uppercase.

> java.sql.SQLException: Table/View 'MYTABLE' already exists in Schema 'APP'.

So, you probably need to use something like

```java
ResultSet rs = metaData.getTables(null, null, "mytable".toUpperCase(), null);
```

in order to get a match.

Comment: The case sensitivity is required by the JDBC specification (eg pattern parameters specify _"must match the table name as it is stored in the database"_), so if a database stores unquoted object names in uppercase, then the pattern should be uppercase as well to match.